# Is there a way to stop href from stripping out localhost from the path

Tags: html, localhost, href

Trying to make a webpage for local&personal use.

I want to have links that point to locations starting with the path \\localhost\C$\

but href strips out localhost and makes it file:///C$/

is there any way to get around this?

I've tried various things, the closest I've had to tricking it was using:

\localhost\C$\

which becomes file:///C:/localhost/C$/

but that still won't work...

Answer (score 0):

you can't access a filesystem via a browser.
You need to call a server that has port 80 opened so you can access.

Maybe you want to access to `http://localhost/`

Therefore you must install and Run a Server (apache, etc) on your local system.